# Div won't vertically align

Tags: html, css

`<div id='loadingScreen'>` has a width of 0 because of the `position:absolute` and the positioning isn't working because of it. Adding a width of 100% to `<div id='loadingScreen'>` doesn't solve the problem.

CSS:

```
        #loadingScreen{
            position:relative;
        }
        .centered{
            height:100px;
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            margin-top:-50px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="loadingScreen">
        <div class="centered">
            <!--stuff-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Making the div absolute makes the width only as long as the content is inside. So if there is no content, the width is 0. And it might be useful to elaborate a bit on your problem rather than posting some CSS without a clear question or describing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: your `#loadingScreen` must have set a height, or your `top:50%` will not work. If you want to use 100% as the `#loadingScreen`-height, then also its parent must have a height defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
.centered
{
    height:200px;           
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Here's a Demo in JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/ireqoc/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
.loadingScreen
{
display:table;
}

.centered
{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do position:absolute, you are effectively placing an object "manually" where you want it to be, meaning it shouldn't automatically align itself.

For normal vertical alignment - try line-height:(div-height); inside your css for .loadingScreen.

If your div is part of a table, try vertical-align:middle; instead.